# How can I store json data from fetch and acess it on react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've created a list of items using a static url that you can touch and open another element. This new element, should open and fetch another url , for example

1
2s
3dd
are urls that I have to concatenate  with another one.

By fetching this I should get the objects and call them on the view.

I have dont know how to map the items and acess them, calling by {id}, or {name} for example.

Comment: can you show a JSON sample for this one?

Comment: {
id:1,
id:2,
id:3
}

Answer (score 0):

If you have just id's in your json response, then call them by index as below;

in your class define array in state

```
 Your class declaration here ... {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
        productExt:[]};

}

  componentDidMount(){
 fetch('Your URL Here')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(result => this.setState({productExt:JSON.stringfy(result)})
  .then(() => console.log("data:" +JSON.stringify(productExt[0]))) ***// this    returns 0 index***
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
} 
}
```

In render you can call object as this.state.productExt[0] or this.state.productExt[1]